# Validate JSON response with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Is it possible to have a Alamofire validator that gets the parsed JSON response, check a property and return true / false depending on that value?

I have an API that always returns 200 response codes, but the response has a success property.

I would like to check this property before the responseJSON callback is fired and only call responseJSON if success == true.

Is this possible with custom validators?

Comment: This seems to be an incredible simple thing to accomplish within the success handler - orthogonal to any underlying network library. You can make this a one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution I feel ok with. First I created extension methods that check for errors and extract the data I'm interested in. I have one success callback and one error callback.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

extension Request {
    public func apiSuccess(
            queue queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil,
            options: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments,
            completionHandler: [String:AnyObject] -> Void)
                    -> Self
    {
        return response(
        queue: queue,
                responseSerializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: options),
                completionHandler: { response in
                    if let jsonValue = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                       let success = jsonValue["success"] as! Bool
                        if (success) {
                            completionHandler(jsonValue["object"] as! [String:AnyObject])
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
    }

    public func apiError(
        queue queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil,
              options: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments,
              completionHandler: [String] -> Void)
        -> Self
    {
        return response(
            queue: queue,
            responseSerializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: options),
            completionHandler: { response in
                if let jsonValue = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    let success = jsonValue["success"] as! Bool
                    if (!success) {
                        let errorDict = jsonValue["errors"] as! [String:[String]]
                        var errors : [String] = []
                        errorDict.keys.forEach { key in
                            errors += errorDict[key] as [String]!
                        }

                        completionHandler(errors)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: .JSON)
            .apiSuccess { response in
                print("Success Callback", response)
            }
            .apiError { errors in
                print("Errors ", errors)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is. Validator blocks don't receive the response data as arguments, only headers and such.

Comment: OK. Maybe I have to write my own version of responseJSON.

Comment: Validator blocks **do** receive the response data. See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/a502949e2d64ac8e15cdbf7fa5353c39bc7cd10e/Source/Validation.swift#L164